# Entity Framework Core - How to identify root entity in change tracker

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to identify in Entity Framework Core 3.1 change tracker which entities are the root entities and which entities are only there because they are referenced by the root entity?

Example:

Person has a car which has a manufacturer.

When updating the person entity, the change tracker will get a hold onto the car and manufacturer entities too. So when retrieving the entries from the change tracker, they will be listed there. And I only want to retrieve the root entity, in this case, the Person entity.

Identify the entity by type will not help because I can have multiple root entities of different types.

```
DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(/*Condition to only identify the root entity, in this case, Person.*/)
```

Thanks!

Comment: First question - why is this important to you? You assume you won't be changing the Car & Manufacturing details in your Person model, will you?  Next, EF Core will return whatever you ask to reference in your query, if you don't want the Car and Manufacturer info - don't `.Include(x => x.Car)`.

Ps. EF is a ORM, not a Domain Model tracker - it's really up to you to design the domain and actions upon the domain, not the other way around. 

Its a bit like asking a database which table in a join is the main one - its not the point.

Comment: What patterns are you using in your application, services, repos, dbcontext etc?

Comment: The entities ARE supposed to be saved, all of them, it is intentional that all the object graph is in there, But I have a specific requirement of identifying the root entities of the change tracker. Actually it is a repository pattern, PersonRepository, and, therefore, the only root entity in there SHOULD be the person entity, but I have to make sure the person is the only root entity.

Comment: Thanks for the initial answer.  However, if you call `var person = _personRespository.GetById(id);` Then isn't `person` obviously the root entity? Is there a specific scenario you need to know more? Or have multiple `root entities` (bit of an oximoron)

Comment: It is a generic repository library, I have no control of the calling code, so the "PersonRepository" could have entities of all different types, I. E. "FoodRepository" could use the same db context and the PersonRepository may end up saving entities from that repository. So I need to identify the root entity, make sure it is of type Person or whatever the type that repository operates and throw if root entities of other types are found.

Comment: So you don't control PersonRepository or FoodRepository?

Comment: No, I only control ```abstract class Repository<TEntity>```. If a root entity type found in the change tracker is of a type different than TEntity, throw.

Comment: Sounds like you have some deep architectural problems. One solution, based on your responses, would be too either speak to your architect, or create an additional abstract layer? (call it Store is you want), FYI, sounds like the Repositories are just a DbContext abstraction rather than a Repository layer.

Comment: Ps. You do not want to invent your own Change Tracker - until you really really need too, and you know why you need too (NB. In 10 years I've only need to do it once)

Comment: Simple answer (not getting to the route problem) is... `var isPerson = TEntity is Person`

Comment: The repository is flexible, it's built to work with UoW (with commit synchronization) or just like a DbContext abstraction, like your said, in the latter approach, identifying different root entities is just a "nice to have" to prevent some folks from saving changes from other repositories unintentionally. UoW is the solution to all of this, the repository supports it, but, like I said, I have no control over who's gonna use it, and they may use it like "standalone" repositories with no UoW.

Comment: In that case, it seems like you want to a Service abstraction above this.... PersonService.Action. Does that fit? NB. Repositories, are really just GetState, UpdateState, CreateNewEntity abstractions - not the hows, whats and wheres - this is a Service layer abstraction.

Comment: The repository is literally just CRUD, no intelligence whatsoever. But on SaveChanges I just wanted to prevent some bad stuff with a simple check. But I guess it's not that easy. But thanks for your help!

Comment: The answer isn’t that it’s not possible, the answer really is - it’s not the right approach to the problem. Hope that make sense

Comment: The root of this problem is that repositories save changes. They shouldn't. Only UoW should. Then it's no longer relevant which repo happened to cause the changes.